# What is this "Comprehensive LaTeX Artifact Novelty" thing?

Tags: ctan

Today, looking for a package on the CTAN, this window popped up:

[image]

Is this for real? Or is it something else?

Comment: april the first :(

Comment: It is! Courtesy of Donald Fauntleroy Knuth, the Grand Wizard of TeX-arcana. `:)`

Comment: What a fool I am! AhAh :D
That's why it has been migrated to tex.stackexchange: to have more fun (of me) :) LoL

Comment: Lol --- thank you for notifying :D -- and please do not downvote this post

Comment: @Naphaneal: And the other question got incredible 18 upvotes (this is ridiculous)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer you want to have a competition and see which one gets the most upvotes? :D

Comment: @Naphaneal: No, I wonder why such questions get that much attention and a lot of other ones/answers get not even proper upvotes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an answer, but I just want to reveal something really, really amusing from this April Fools joke: the text refers to the acquisition of TeX by a company located at Shanghai, China. Now, the symbol portrayed in the right side of the message,

[image: Symbol]

is, not surprisingly, a Chinese symbol for insanity. Clever, isn't it? `:)`

Comment: not the first.  see http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb19-2/tb59hoax.pdf for another.  (that one appeared on line, and was then published in the ntg maps with *no* warning!  total consternation!)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Oh my! `:)`