# Why does CTAN now look like I'm on LSD?

Tags: fun, ctan

It seems that the CTAN network has been updated to appear as if users are on hard drugs or in the twilight zone. The moving background is making me dizzy.

This is not the same as [What is CTAN.org now?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301882/what-is-ctan-org-now) because it is (was) not April Fool's Day. There you have it. I have explained why this question is unique for that one person who wanted to know why.

[image]

## LSD

[image]

## Twilight Zone

[image]

Comment: Halloween special I imagine.

Comment: halloween skin: http://www.ctan.org/user/settings

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Phew. Good grief. I was scared for a minute.

Comment: the scariest part is `tabularx`

Comment: The `verbatim` is coming from **inside** the `tabularx`!!!

Comment: also see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6912/has-ctan-site-changed-its-look

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301927/what-is-this-comprehensive-latex-artifact-novelty-thing

Comment: If the April Fools question isn't closed an has more than 60 upvotes, why close this one as off-topic? It is the same funny stuff we appreciate once in a while.

Comment: @Joseph Wright I'm not the only one to have fallen into the trap!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Welcome to the twilight zone!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is CTAN.org now?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301882/what-is-ctan-org-now)

Comment: @StrongBad I am glad I asked this question. I hope it gave most people a laugh.

Comment: Just to be thorough: @macmadness86, are you on LSD? :-P

Comment: @DavidZ I am not aware of having taken LSD, haha. It did come into question upon seeing seeing the CTAN website.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The 31st of October is the day of a festival called [Halloween](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween).  This custom was established long time ago to scare away ghosts by dressing up as spooky creatures oneself.  It is common to decorate your house with horrifying accessories and since CTAN is the home of TeX it is all Halloween-themed today.

**HAPPY HALLOWEEN!**

---

Related:

- [Draw a turkey, a pumpkin pie, or any other object traditionally associated with Thanksgiving](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279788)
- [Seasonal Challenge (Contributions from TeXing Dead Welcome)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336768)

For a spooky browser game [click here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/undead.html).

Comment: You forgot to add that Halloween is a dialectal form of "All Hallows Eve" which is also dialectal for All Hallows Evening, the evening (and I suppose day of Nov. 1) before All Saints Day. I completely forgot about it today. I guess the ghosts will get me...

Comment: @macmadness86 True, but for everyone interested in such details I put the Wikipedia link.

Comment: You haven't seen the upgrade: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336768/seasonal-challenge-contributions-from-texing-dead-welcome!

Comment: Just in case... set a theme in Settings.

Comment: @JonathanKomar Actually “eve” is a word on its own, archaically “even” from ”æfen” (same origin as German “Abend”) from which “evening” developed.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to return to the normal site skin on the site's [user settings page](https://ctan.org/user/settings) (login not required).

I found the halloween skin (and especially the *sound effects*) quite tasteless.